# How to disable double escaping url in golang?

Tags: go

It looks like golang reverseproxy double escapes url, when making a http request,

server receives:

```
/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%252BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%252FEGs7f
```

expected:

```
/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%2BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%2FEGs7f
```

Is there a way to avoid double escaping?

Comment: I'm doing a proxy pass and want to pass the url path as is. `/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%2BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%2FEGs7f` is valid url, not sure why it double escapes? If I url decode that becomes a wrong url isn't it? `/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa+IFVla4ZdfRiMzfh/EGs7f`

Comment: Ok, I'm using echo framework (https://github.com/labstack/echo), and I basically want to add oAuth token + have dynamic mapping of routing in my orchestrator using Proxy with Rewrite (https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/rewrite). However, I have some urls like mentioned above and it's getting double escaped by go http when doing reverse proxy call.

Comment: @MuffinTop - Yes the goal is to make the call with URI `/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%2BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%2FEGs7f`

Comment: For anyone with similar issue with double escape in reverse proxy, this issue was fixed in go 1.1.5. More details here github.com/golang/go/issues/41082#issuecomment-682283012

Answer (score 1):

Go isn't double-escaping the URL. It's constructing the URL given the values that you gave it (which means escaping the path). You've already escaped the path. Don't do that. If you want to send `+`, then use `+`. Go will escape it correctly.

If you have an escaped path already for some reason, then unescape it with `url.PathUnescape()` before constructing the URL.

Comment: What if the path has a slash `/`?

Comment: @ArunGopalpuri I don't understand the question. Slash is a normal character for the path.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is build a proxy and pass the path as is to the other server. So say I want to pass `/foo%2fbar` as path but the server on the other end is receiving `/foo%252fbar`

Comment: That's very unusual. `/foo%2fbar` should be interpreted identically to `/foo/bar` according to most specs. Is your system not interpreting %2f in the standard way? Why is the first `/` being sent raw, but the second is percent-encoded?

Comment: That was just an example. In my case its a system Id as path parameter (unfortunately its not url safe i.e. consists of slashes and hash) so I'm passing it encoded in url as  `/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%2BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%2FEGs7f` but the server receiving it on the other end is getting it as `/id/EbnfwIoiiXbtr6Ec44sfedeEsjrf0RcXkJneYukTXa%252BIFVla4ZdfRiMzfh%252FEGs7f`

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's url safe. That's the job of `url` to do for you. Just pass it to `url` and let it do all the encoding. You're seeing that that `url` is trying to send just what you said you wanted. You said you wanted to send `%2f` and to send that and url needs to encode the percent. But you don't mean that. You mean you want to send `/`, so just pass `/`. Or are you saying that your system doesn't treat `/` the same as `%2f` (according to spec) and you need to do some kind of non-standard encoding?

Comment: Think I have to set Path as unescaped url and RawPath as encoded url and now I see it constructing the url as I want the server to receive it? I got it send the encoded url this way (rawEncodedURL) -> https://play.golang.org/p/rOrVzW8ZJCQ